# socket set blocking raising OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: python, sockets, unix

I am creating a socket and using it to communicate to python processes.

I create the socket this way because I already have a file descriptor:

```
sock = socket.fromfd(fd, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

If I receive a lot of requests it will raise a  [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable.

> When the message does not fit into the send buffer of the socket,
>   send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in
>   nonblocking I/O mode. In nonblocking mode it would fail with the error
>   EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in this case. The select(2) call may be used to
>   determine when it is possible to send more data.

Then it looks like it was in nonblocking I/O mode and it was raising EAGAIN error.

So I set it to blocking:

```
sock.setblocking(1)
```

But I keep having the same error. Also the socket.fromfd documentation says:

> The socket is assumed to be in blocking mode

Comment: When you say "*it* will raise..." do you mean you are getting that exception from the `socket.fromfd` call?

Comment: I have another method which sends data through the socket wrapped in a try except OSError, e: which raises the Errno 11.

Comment: AFAIK, you should only get `EAGAIN` (errno 11) on a `send` call if (a) the socket is set to non-blocking, or (b) there is a timeout set with `setsockopt(...,  SO_SNDTIMEO, ...)`

Comment: That's what I thought but as you can see I set it to nonblocking and I am not using any timeout...

Answer (score -4):

Firstly, I have no idea what a "python process" is.  A process is a process.  What language something is written in, or what interpreter may be interpreting something, has nothing to do with anything.

Next, I am not sure what "I create the socket this way because I already have a file descriptor" means.  I don't see you creating anything, but, rather, assigning some value from a structure to another variable.

Not knowing how you ORIGINALLY instantiated ***socket***, it is not possible to guess what the resource issue might be.

Comment: Literally the third line of my question is instantiating a socket:

socket.fromfd(fd, family, type[, proto])
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.fromfd

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you need clarification, ask your question in the comment section.